# can't modify char* - Memory access violation

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, char

Why does it say "Memory access violation"?

```
  char* str = "HelloGuys";
  int len = strlen(str);
  for (int i=0; i<(len/2); ++i){
        char t = str[len-i-1];
        str[len-i-1] = str[i]; //error
        str[i] = t;
  }
```

Comment: The language is stupid in this regard: it allows an erroneous conversion from `const char[]` to `char*`. That is, is implicitly strips away the `const`, tricking you into thinking it's modifiable. It's not. (This conversion has been removed in C++0x.)

Comment: @GMan : There is not much of a difference between C and C++ string literals. Whether all the string literal are distinct is implementation defined in C++ and in C it is unspecified. But as far as this question is concerned any attempt to modify the content of the string literal would invoke undefined behaviour in C as well as in C++. So taking into consideration the above code the difference is negligible.

Comment: @Prasoon: The technically reason why is different, though. (Technically your answer has the wrong reasoning, I mean.) Both say "don't modify string literals, or you get undefined behavior", but C++ does it by making the literals `const`, and C does it just by saying "modifying a string literal (which has the type `char[]`) leads to undefined behavior". My revert might not make total sense, because earlier there were comments here (now are now deleted) where me and another discussed the technical differences, and having both tags made it ambiguous and confusing.

Comment: @GMan and what "string literals" actually is? const char* ?

Comment: @VectoR: Depends on the string. They are an array of `const char`, though, with static storage. Think of `"asd"` as the name of a global variable, as in: `static const char "asd"[4] = { 'a', 's', 'd', 0 };`. Arrays can be implicitly converted to pointers to their first element. So `const char[]` can turn into `const char*`, but not `char*` because that would remove the `const`. The special case is strings, which *does* allow such an implicit loss of `const`.

Comment: @PrasoonSaurav actually `char* str = "HelloGuys"`  is illegal code according to standard, that's some compilers still use it as an extension to be compatible with really ancient code. It should be `const char* str`

Comment: Though already answered, I would like to tag from the CERT SEI Coding Standard maintained by CMU https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/x/VtYxBQ

Answer (score 22, accepted):

String literals are stored in read only section of memory. Any attempt to modify the contents of a string literal invokes Undefined Behaviour (segmentation fault on most implementations).

Use an array of characters rather

```
char str[] = "HelloGuys";
```

Comment: still cannot modify individual characters within the array

Comment: String literals *might be* stored in read only section of memory

Answer (score 1):

As Prasoon already said, string literals are not modifiable.

If you need a modifiable array of chars have it like this:

```
char str[] = "HelloGuys";
```

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour is undefined if a program attempts to modify any portion of a string literal (most compiler chose to raise a "Memory access violation" error). The most important thing is to identify when you are trying to modify string literals and when you are not.

This is ok:

```
 char str[]  = "string literal";
 str[0] = 'S';
```

You have made a copy of the string literal. You are not modifying the string literal, but the array str.

This is not ok:

```
 char *str  = "string literal";
 str[0] = 'S';
```

You never made a copy of the string; the pointer is pointing to the string literal itself.
You are attempting to modify the string literal.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, use an array instead of a pointer to read-only memory:

```
char str[] = "HelloGuys";   // change this line
int len = strlen(str);
for (int i=0; i<(len/2); ++i){
    char t = str[len-i-1];
    str[len-i-1] = str[i];
    str[i] = t;
}
```