# Segmentation-fault under MingW, when changing character in string

Tags: c, gcc, segmentation-fault, mingw

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [can’t modify char* - Memory access violation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343721/cant-modify-char-memory-access-violation)

Been tracking down a problem in a c-program I compile with MingW,
and it finally boiled down to the very simple testcase below.

The intention, of course, is to change a character in a string.
But this code gives me a Segmentation fault.
Can someone please explain why? I dont get it...

test.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(){
  char *s = "xx";
  printf("(%s)\n", s);
  s[0] = 'z';  // ** Segmentation fault here **
  printf("(%s)\n", s);
}
```

--

```
$ gcc -c test.c
$ gcc -o test.exe test.o
$ ./test.exe
(xx)
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: Duplicate hundreds of times over.

Comment: Short answer - attempting to modify a string literal causes undefined behaviour.  You probably meant to use `char s[] = "xx";`.

Comment: Editorial note - it is sloppy programming to not declare the return type of `main()`.

Comment: Is this specific to MingW? Or to Windows? AFAIK, it works in every *nix environment I have used.

Comment: maybe you got lucky.  Any relatively modern machine (with memory protection) will show the same behaviour you see.  Undefined behaviour can sometimes appear to produce working code, but that's telling yourself lies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string "xx" can be allocated into read-only memory by the compiler.  Hence, when you try to change that memory, if it has been allocated to read-only memory you'll get a segmentation fault.

In cases that your string size is fixed, such as in your example, if you define the string as a character array that memory will not be allocated read-only and you will not have that problem.

Sometimes, you don't know the string's maximum size or you don't want to waste space, so you'd need to malloc() that memory, use strdup() (which allocates memory as part of its function), or something similar.

Comment: `malloc` is pretty heavyweight for this program.  Simply declaring an array will suffice.

Comment: @Carl: This is a very sensible point and I think that that part of my answer was much more wrong than not given the OP's code.  I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help.

So for the records, this works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void main(){
  char s[] = "xx";
  // or: char *s = malloc(5); strcpy(s, "xx");
  printf("(%s)\n", s);
  s[0] = 'z';  // ** Segmentation fault here **
  printf("(%s)\n", s);
}
```