# Exchange two c-strings

Tags: c++

I'm trying to exchange the value of two cstrings, but I keep on getting errors. At first I tried using for loops to individually exchange the value of each element in each array, but now I'm trying to use the strcpy() function. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void exchange(char * &, char * &);
int main()
{
    char * s1 = "Hello";
    char * s2 = "Bye Bye";

    exchange(* & s1, * & s2);

    cout << "s1 = " << s1 << endl; //"Bye Bye" should be displayed
    cout << "s2 = " << s2 << endl; // "Hello" should be displayed
    return 0;
}
void exchange(char * & p1, char * & p2)
{
    int size;
    if (strlen(*& p2) > strlen(*& p1))
    {
        size = strlen(*& p2);
    }
    else
    {
        size = strlen(*& p1);
    }

    char * temp;
    temp = new char[size];

    strcpy(*&temp, *&p1);
    strcpy(*&p1, *&p2);
    strcpy(*&p2, *&temp);
}
```

Comment: So why does this not work? (You must be getting a segfault. There is a reason for that.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [can't modify char\* - Memory access violation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343721/cant-modify-char-memory-access-violation)

Answer (score 0):

You need a solution like [std::swap](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap):

```
std::swap(s1, s2);
```

The output will be:

```
s1 = Bye Bye
s2 = Hello
```

Answer (score -2):

I figured it out, all I had to do, instead of everything in the function exchange, put:

```
char * temp;
temp = new char[];

temp = p1;
p1 = p2;
p2 = temp;
```

Comment: Who cleans up the memory allocated for `temp` now? And why not use `std::swap(p1, p2)`?

Comment: There's no reason to allocate a new array here.