# How can I do "rot-13 decode" in MFC?

Tags: c++, mfc

Well, I want to make a function which have encoding and decoding function.
So, I studied about "rot-13 encoding" and solved it like this:

```
char* szTemp = "Hello World";
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(szTemp); i++)
{
    if       (szTemp[i] >= 'a' && szTemp[i] <= 'm') szTemp[i] += 13;
    else if  (szTemp[i] >= 'A' && szTemp[i] <= 'M') szTemp[i] += 13;
    else if  (szTemp[i] >= 'n' && szTemp[i] <= 'z') szTemp[i] -= 13;
    else if  (szTemp[i] >= 'N' && szTemp[i] <= 'Z') szTemp[i] -= 13;
}
MessageBox(szTemp);
```

But it have some error. What is it? Anyone help me!

Comment: You're trying to [modify a read-only literal string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343721/cant-modify-char-memory-access-violation). I'd start by fixing that. `char szTemp[] = "Hello, World!";`

Comment: `char* szTemp` is *not* read only.  You just have to make sure you don't write past the size of the buffer.

Comment: @DexStar memory it points to is read only. First line should not even compile on modern standards, but even in dark ages, attempt to modify string literal is UB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MFC, it's all about the `CString`...

```
    CString sTemp = "Hello World";
    CString sResult = "";
    int nLength = sTemp.GetLength();
    char c;

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < nLength ; ++i )
    {
        c = sTemp[i];
        if       (c>= 'a' && c<= 'm') c+= 13;
        else if  (c>= 'A' && c<= 'M') c+= 13;
        else if  (c>= 'n' && c<= 'z') c-= 13;
        else if  (c>= 'N' && c<= 'Z') c-= 13;
        sResult += c;
    }

    AfxMessageBox( sResult );
```

It can also be done by accessing the buffer directly, in which case, you can use almost all of your original code.  It looks something like this:

```
    CString sTemp = "Hello World";
    int nLength = sTemp.GetLength();

    // Limit scope of szTemp since it is not usable after 
    // the call to ReleaseBuffer
    {
        char* szTemp = sTemp.GetBuffer();

        for (int i = 0; i < nLength; i++)
        {
            if       (szTemp[i] >= 'a' && szTemp[i] <= 'm') szTemp[i] += 13;
            else if  (szTemp[i] >= 'A' && szTemp[i] <= 'M') szTemp[i] += 13;
            else if  (szTemp[i] >= 'n' && szTemp[i] <= 'z') szTemp[i] -= 13;
            else if  (szTemp[i] >= 'N' && szTemp[i] <= 'Z') szTemp[i] -= 13;
        }
        sTemp.ReleaseBuffer();
    }

    AfxMessageBox( sTemp );
```

Hope that helps,
D*