# Why does this results in a segmentation fault?

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{
    char *p = "I like C++";
    strcpy(p, "John Smith");
    std::cout << p << std::endl;
    EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

As the title stated, why does this results in segmentation fault

Comment: There should be similar questions with answers on the site. I'll try to look for them. The gist of it is that "I like C++" is a string literal (which is constant) and `p` points to it. Attempting to modify it is undefined behavior, hence the crash. If you want a character array which you can modify, you want to declare it as `char p[] = "I like C++";`

Comment: Because you can't modify a *String-Literal* in all but strange and wonky OSs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [can't modify char\* - Memory access violation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343721/cant-modify-char-memory-access-violation)

Comment: This code is ill-formed; if you don't see a compilation error then adjust your compiler settings as you are wasting time trying to run illegal code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Speaking in the terms used by `strcpy()` [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/), you are trying to copy "John Smith" (the `source` argument) into `p` (the `destination` argument).

Although `p` is a pointer of type `char *`, it resides in the read-only data section (`.rodata` probably).

Trying to copy a new string into it, means trying to write over read-only memory.

Changing the declaration to `char p[] = "I like C++";` fixes the issue as `p` now resides on the stach which is both readable and writeable memory.

By the way, the last line is missing a `return` and should be `return EXIT_SUCCESS`.